# Ensuring that only one instance of a function is running?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++, visual-c++-2017

I'm just getting into concurrent programming. Most probably my issue is very common, but since I can't find a good name for it, I can't google it.

I have a C++ UWP application where I try to apply MVVM pattern, but I guess that the pattern or even being UWP is not relevant.

First, I have a service interface that exposes an operation:

```
struct IService
{
    virtual task<int> Operation() = 0;
};
```

Of course, I provide a concrete implementation, but it is not relevant for this discussion. The operation is potentially long-running: it makes an HTTP request.

Then I have a class that uses the service (again, irrelevant details omitted):

```
class ViewModel
{
    unique_ptr<IService> service;
public:
    task<void> Refresh();
};
```

I use coroutines:

```
task<void> ViewModel::Refresh()
{
    auto result = co_await service->Operation();
    // use result to update UI
}
```

The Refresh function is invoked on timer every minute, or in response to a user request. What I want is: if a Refresh operation is already in progress when a new one is started or requested, then abandon the second one and just wait for the first one to finish (or time out). In other words, I don't want to queue all the calls to Refresh - if a call is already in progress, I prefer to skip a call until the next timer tick.

My attempt (probably very naive) was:

```
mutex refresh;
task<void> ViewModel::Refresh()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(refresh, try_to_lock);
    if (!lock)
    {
        // lock.release(); commented out as harmless but useless => irrelevant
        co_return;
    }
    auto result = co_await service->Operation();
    // use result to update UI
}
```

**Edit after the original post: I commented out the line in the code snippet above, as it makes no difference. The issue is still the same.**

But of course an assertion fails: `unlock of unowned mutex`. I guess that the problem is the `unlock` of `mutex` by `unique_lock` destructor, which happens in the continuation of the coroutine and on a different thread (other than the one it was originally locked on).

Using Visual C++ 2017.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I haven't tried, but I'm open to any suggestions - can you give a code example?

Comment: Truly naive solution: `std::atomic<bool> running`.

Comment: Don't you think the problem is more about the fact that you're trying to release a lock that you know isn't locked?

Comment: What about making a static instance counter?

Comment: @UKMonkey, no, the problem is not the release of the lock. The reasons are numerous, so let's just say that the issue remains even if the line is removed. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `std::atomic_bool`:

```
std::atomic_bool isRunning = false;
if (isRunning.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acq_rel) == false){
   try{
    auto result = co_await Refresh();
    isRunning.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    //use result 
   }
   catch(...){
     isRunning.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
     throw;
   }
}
```

Two possible improvements : wrap `isRunning.store` in a RAII class and use `std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_bool>` if the lifetime if the `atomic_bool` is scoped.

Comment: The solution works, and there is no other (not here, at least), so I accept it. However I have two comments. 1) I am disappointed by the fact that the standard library does not offer a standard solution. This is not to diminish the value of the answer. 2) Couldn't `std::atomic_bool` be replaced by `std::atomic_flag`? `std:atomic_bool` offers more features (more control), but what additional value does it provide? Understood that it is optimisation of some sort, but how significant is it?

Comment: 1) this *is* a standard solution 2) `std::atomic_flag` can be used here, although personally I would expect `std::atomic_flag` to be used only with `std::call_once`.